# How to adjust table size to div size?

Tags: html, css

How to adjust table size to div size where are in?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Wanarka, Can you share the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it `display: inline-block;`and give it a width and height.

Give the basic Bootstrap grid system a try, very easy to use and gives a lot of options. [Link](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)